# PayPal is sending many multiples of the same webhook (node)

Tags: node.js, paypal, sdk, webhooks, paypal-rest-sdk

Update: Code is now working, I think there were a ton of unverified transactions that had to work their way back through the system after I added `res.send('on') to the code.

Edit: Adding `res.send('on')` fixed the 502 gateway error but the re-sending continues.

I have webhooks successfully configured and am receiving them at my listener. The documentation on how to verify is not very clear, but I am running the code for `get_and_ verify.js` given in the node SDK docs. Each webhook that is sent by PayPal is run through this code, which consistently returns `true`.

My issue is, PayPal is re-sending the same webhook over and over again, seemingly endlessly. Is there something I have not done in the configuration, or is this just how these work?

listener code:

```
app.post('/paymentauthed', (req,res) => {
        res.status(200);
        console.log(req.body);

paypal.configure({
  mode: "sandbox", //sandbox or live
  client_id:
    "...",
  client_secret:
    "..."
});

const eventBody = `{"id": "${req.body.id}"}`
paypal.notification.webhookEvent.getAndVerify(eventBody, function (error, response) {
   if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw error;
    } else {
        console.log(response);
    }
});

});
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server Started'))
```

this response might be relevant also, it says there is a 502 bad gateway, not sure why...

```
"transmissions": [
        {
            "webhook_url": "https://cloudhookstester.net/paymentauthed",
            "response_headers": {
                "SERVER_INFO": "",
                "Strict-Transport-Security": "“max-age=15768000”",
                "HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway": "",
                "Server": "nginx/1.14.2",
                "Connection": "keep-alive",
                "Content-Length": "173",
                "Date": "Tue, 15 Jan 2019 03:38:43 GMT",
                "Content-Type": "text/html"
            },
            "transmission_id": "74323070-1874-11e9-8941-d953a11868e8",
            "status": "PENDING",
            "timestamp": "2019-01-15T03:20:05Z"
        }
    ],
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you found a solution?

Comment: I fixed it by fixing the "bad gateway" error

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem while implementing receiving paypal webhook in my django application, this is resolved after giving a valid working URL over a server for webhook call with returning **HttpResponse**.

Hope It will work for you and other people are getting this problem also.